# What is the easiest way to accomplish textual tick labels in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Consider the following simple PV-diagram:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/U9nxbJU.png?1]

The code below created it and the output is fine. I used kind of a workaround with an array to get the right tick labels on both of the axes. That works fine for low values, but if I want to set for instance `V_f = 200`, getting the tick label right is going to be a bit of a problem.

What's a proper fix to get the tick labels? Can I tell `tikz` to use the "next" element of my array every time it actually printed the tick? I could think of a solution which increments a counter only when the printing happens, but surely there's a `tikz` solution for this ?

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,arrows.meta, decorations.markings,backgrounds, intersections}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
    nomorepostaction/.code=\makeatletter\let\tikz@postactions\pgfutil@empty, 
    my axis/.style={
        postaction={
            decoration={
                markings,
                mark=at position 1 with {
                    \arrow[ultra thick]{latex}
                }
            },
            decorate,
            nomorepostaction
        },
        thin,
        -, % switch off other arrow tips
        every path/.append style=my axis % this is necessary so it works both with "axis lines=left" and "axis lines=middle"
    }
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\def\xt{{0,"$V_i=1$",0,"$V_f=3$"}}\relax
\def\yt{{0,"$P_i=1$",0,"$P_f=3$"}}\relax
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines=left,
    width=.95\linewidth,
    axis line style={my axis},
    xmin = 0, xmax = 4,
    ymin = 0, ymax = 4,
    xticklabel={\pgfmathparse{\xt[\tick]}\pgfmathresult},
    xtick={1,3},
    yticklabel={\pgfmathparse{\yt[\tick]}\pgfmathresult},
    ytick={1,3},
    xlabel={Volume},
    ylabel={Pressure}
    ]
  \path[name path=axisa] (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},1) -- (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},1);
  \path[name path=axisb] (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},3) -- (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},3);
\addplot[name path=graph, black,very thick,  -latex ] coordinates
        {(1,1) (3,3)} 
        ;
   \path[name intersections={of=axisa and graph, by={interpa}}];
      \path[name intersections={of=axisb and graph, by={interpb}}];
   \draw[ultra thin, dashed] (axis cs:0,1) -- (interpa);
   \draw[ultra thin, dashed] (axis cs:1,0) -- (interpa);
   \draw[ultra thin, dashed] (axis cs:0,3) -- (interpb);
   \draw[ultra thin, dashed] (axis cs:3,0) -- (interpb);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why do you decorate instead of putting arrows on the axis lines? Besides, if there are two values automation is not worth it? Do you have sometinhg else in mind?

Comment: @percusse It's a solution I took directly from another question which I didn't want to break with whatever solution one could come up with to my question here. I'm sure there are alternative ways to customize the axis arrows, but this is the one I found. The automation is for extended (more complicated) versions. I thought I'd start off with something simple. `:-)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you looking for the `xticklabels` and `yticklabels` option? The ticklabels in the `xticklabels` list are assigned to the tick positions given by the `xtick` list.

Example:

```
xtick={10,30},
xticklabels={$V_i=10$,$V_f=30$},
```

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots} % loads also tikz
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines=left,
    axis line style=-{Latex[scale=1.5]},
    width=.95\linewidth,
    xmin = 0, xmax = 40,
    ymin = 0, ymax = 40,
    xtick={10,30},
    xticklabels={$V_i=10$,$V_f=30$},
    ytick={10,30},
    yticklabels={$P_i=10$,$P_f=30$},
    xlabel={Volume},
    ylabel={Pressure}
  ]
  \addplot[very thick,-latex ] coordinates{(10,10) (30,30)}
    coordinate[at start](interpa)coordinate[at end](interpb);
  \pgfplotsinvokeforeach {a,b}{
    \draw[ultra thin, dashed] 
      ({axis cs:0,0}|-interp#1)--(interp#1)--(interp#1|-{axis cs:0,0});}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```